# Error: Element type is invalid thrown by reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

for the code below in next.js index page

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
const theme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial'
    },

    fontFamily: 'Arial'

});

function index () {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2">Minimumdd 6 Characters</Typography>
    );
};

export default index;
```

It gives

> "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
> imports."

[image]

May I know what am I doing incorrectly?

Here's the entire stacktrace from the console

> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at index.js:15.
> at Home
> at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:11:18)
> at StyleRegistry (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js:671:34)
> at FlushEffectContainer (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:424:37)
> at AppContainer (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:439:29)
> at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:470:57)
> at div
> at Body (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:736:21)
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> at renderElement (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5833:9)
> at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5875:11)
> at renderContextProvider (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5710:3)
> at renderElement (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5807:11)
> at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5875:11)
> at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5575:7)
> at renderElement (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5736:7)
> at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5875:11)
> at renderContextProvider (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5710:3)
> at renderElement (C:\Dev\astatic_web\frontend_js\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5807:11)
> wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)... wait  - compiling...
> event - compiled client and server successfully in 188 ms (470
> modules) error - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.

Here's the development console if it's helpful:
[image]

Comment: Hey, can you show us the entire stack trace?

Comment: This wierd thing often happen, Did you used to "<index /> or <Index />  (first letter uppercase matters matters) when using this component ?

Comment: @OsmanCorluk this is next.js, so the component is at the root level

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to `Index` with the capital `I`. I don't know next.js,, but it seems like the name matters.
So the file should be `index.js` and component name `Index`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, i have later change it to `Home`, as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: @william007 yes it is `Home`, but the file is `index.js` you should have `home.js` as a file or `Index` as a component

Comment: It looks like Typography is the default export from `@mui/material/Typography`. Have you tried removing the braces from your import statement?

Comment: @samuei bingo!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the typography in the createTheme function needs to be capitalized to match the component name? A way around this could be directly inserting the font family as a prop to Typography, but that's tedious. Maybe set the body of the app to have your desired font.